# The fastest growing function of given complexity

Tags: computability-theory, kolmogorov-complexity

Let $f$ be a computable function $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$
be a computable function. Since a program of a computable function is a finite object we can define plain Kolmogorov complexity of $f$ (we can identify programs as Turing machines, for example).

Now I will talk only about total computable functions.

1) Is there a function $f$ with complexity not greater than $d + O(1)$ such that for every $g \in \mathcal{F}_d$---the set of function with complexity atmost $d$---and for every $x \in \mathbb{N}$ it holds that $f(x) \ge g(x)$?

More precisely: Is there $C$ such that for every $d$ there exists $f$ with Kolmogorov complexity at most $d + C$ such that for every $g$ with Kolmogorov complexity at most $d$ and for every $x \in \mathbb{N}$ it holds that $f(x) \ge g(x)$?

2) Is there a function $f$ with complexity not greater than $d + O(1)$ that  growing at $\infty$  faster than any function in $\mathcal{F}_d$, i.e. there exists $C$ such that for every $g \in \mathcal{F}_d$ and for every $x >C$ it holds that $f(x) \ge g(x)$?

3) Is there a rather small subset $F$ (say, $|F| = \text{poly}(d)$) of functions with complexity not greater than $d + O(1)$  such that for every $g\in \mathcal{F}_d$ there exists $f \in F$ that grows faster than $g$?

Comment: This could depend heavily on the exact definition of Kolmogorov complexity. Do you have anything precise in mind?

Comment: @Wojowu, I think you mean that it can depend on the way of the representation of functions and the choice of optimal decompressor? I agree with it. It is better to restrict the complexity of $f$ by $d + O(1)$. I will fix it, thank you

Comment: To me the question is even more confusing after changing to $d+O(1)$. What does *a function $f$ with complexity not greater than $d+O(1)$* exactly mean? It's as ambiguous as the phrase *a number not greater than $d+O(1)$*. I suggest that you rephrase your question in standard first order logic statements instead of notions such as $O(1)$. For the ambiguity of Kolmogorov complexity, it's perhaps better to fix a language first and then argue the effect of changing the language.

Comment: Is $d$ meant to be a constant, or a function of $x$? If the idea is that $d$ is constant, then it seems like you could 'run' all the $g\in\mathcal{F}_d$ and take the largest of them (plus 1, if you want). This will give you a larger constant $d'$ (dependent on $d$, of course) and a function $f\in\mathcal{F}_{d'}$ that satisfies 1)...

Comment: @WhatsUp I have wrote more precisely. Is it clear now?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki the constant in $O(1)$ should not depend on $d$. I have wrote more precisely.

Comment: Yes, part 1 is now a clear statement to me.

Comment: Is this plain complexity or prefix-free?  With plain, the answer to 2 is yes, since d + O(1) bits is enough to specify how many functions of complexity at most d are total.  So a function can wait until that many have converged up to a given value, then output the max.

Comment: @DanTuretsky But what if for given $x$, the computation of $g(x)$ converges even though $g$ is not total?

Comment: @Wojowu You wait until you see the appropriate number converging on all $y \le x$.  For sufficiently large $x$, all non-total $g$ of complexity $\le d$ will fail to converge on some $y \le x$.  This is why it works for 2 but not 1.

Comment: @DanTuretsky I see, clever!

Answer (score 1):

Alexander Shen gave the full answer: https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.02844